# [Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: redux, react-redux

This is my error:

> err [Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the
> body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>    and fix this problem.]

Code:

```js
let url = config.baseURL + 'home_data.php?user_id=' + user_id + '&APP_VERSION=1';
    consolepro.consolelog('url', url);
    apifuntion
      .getApi(url)
      .then(obj => {
        if (obj.success == 'true') {
          consolepro.consolelog('homedataooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo', obj);

          const dispatch = useDispatch();
          const dataFromObj = useSelector(state => state.Reducers);

          consolepro.consolelog("dattttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt", dataFromObj)

          dispatch(getDataMethod(obj));

          check_notification_num = obj.check_notification_num;
          // (main_category_arr = obj.category_arr);
          config.content_arr = obj.content_arr;
          if (config.device_type == 'ios') {
            config.guest_status = obj.guest_status;
          } else {
            config.guest_status = false;
          }

          localStorage.setItemObject('user_arr', obj.user_details);
          this.setState({
            category_arr: obj.category_arr,
            new_item: obj.all_product,
          });
        } else {
          if (
            obj.active_status == '0' ||
            obj.msg[config.language] == msgTitle.usernotexit[config.language]
          ) {
            config.checkUserDeactivate(this.props.navigation);
          } else {
            msgProvider.alert(
              msgTitle.information[config.language],
              obj.msg[config.language],
              false,
            );
          }
          return false;
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        consolepro.consolelog('err', err);
      });
```

I'm creating a project and my data come from a PHP database but it's too slow.

so I use redux but it's given me the error. I don't know how to use redux in-class component but I know how to use in a function component

Can anyone give me a simple full example of class component with redux in react native?

Comment: Is there any jsx code in this file?

Comment: I don't know because I'm not creating this

Comment: I mean is there any return statement which returns UI in this file?

Comment: I want value in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure this file is a React function component. Hooks can only be called from the body of a function component.

Second, move these lines to the root scope of the component:

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const dataFromObj = useSelector(state => state.Reducers);
```

Hooks cannot be called from the scope of other functions.

Comment: I want redux in class component

Comment: Then you can't use hooks.

Comment: so I can't use redux in class component ?

Comment: You can use Redux, but you have to look up how to do it without hooks.

Comment: okay! so can you give me any reference

Comment: https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/connect